# Запомнить checkbox

Tags: mysqli, html, php, css

Подскажите как сделать, я вот делаю админку, и у меня есть функция отключение сайта:

Отключить сайт:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yes">    
<button>Сохранить</button>
```

Если я выключил сайт, то есть нажал на `checkbox` и нажал сохранить, перезагрузил страницу и `checkbox` остался нажатым то есть галочка поставлена(более проще) если я снял её и нажал сохранить то разуметься она снялась(флажок).

Comment: сохраните в куке

Comment: куки навсегда можно сделать?

Comment: ну на счет навсегда точно не знаю, думаю что можно как то намудрить, но на <> года точно можете

Comment: @bemulima нет. Куки тут не спасут. Только запись в бд. Ведь речь идёт о настройках сайта! А тем более - ты можешь нажатьэту кнопку за одним браузером, далеко ходить не надо - в другом браузере из-за гтсутствия куков эта кнопка будет активна. Неа. Чуть ниже есть ответ, мол базу данных юзать. Я в код не вникал, но если он рабочий, то это куда лучше куков. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам требуется выключение сайта, то скорее всего информация о статусе сайта будет храниться в БД. Как правило для таких целей заводят таблицу settings, из которой вытягиваются нужные данные. К примеру будет поле STATUS_SITE с полем enum(0,1) . 0 - сайт выключен, 1 - включен. При загрузке кода админки вытягиваем данные из таблицы settings и (так я делал) создаём в цикле переменные `define($row['name_settings'],$row['value_settings'])`. В нашем случае мы получим строку `define('STATUS_SITE','0'`).
При загрузке чекбокса статуса сайта проверяем:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="yes"';
if(STATUS_SITE == 1){
    echo ' checked';
};
echo '>';
```

При нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" перезаписывайте значение value_settings для строки STATUS_SITE:

```
query("update settings set value_settings = '".$_POST['status_site']."' where name_settings = 'STATUS_SITE'");
```